# CakePHP 1.1.6 how to break out of ajax layout to the default layout

Tags: ajax, cakephp, redirect

I have a legacy application using CakePHP 1.1.6 and I am updating it. I have an ajax form submission which updates a div after a series of ajax requests. All is working well until I want to return to the main menu page of the app. I can't figure how to get out of the ajax layout with the final redirect into the default layout on the menu page.
I've tried various methods of overwriting the redirect() method without success. Has anyone managed this in v1.1.6? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By "AJAX layout" is suspect you simply mean a *URL prefix* or something of that kind.
E.g. all URLs like `/ajax/foo/bar` are displayed with an AJAX layout,
and a simple `redirect(array('action' => 'baz'))` generates `/ajax/foo/baz`.

It kind of depends on how your routes are set up, but usually you just set the specific prefix to `false`:

```
$this->redirect(array('ajax' => false, 'controller' => 'normal', 'action' => 'home'));
```

Comment: What I'm doing is displaying items the user is going to save to a database but asking for verification before the save happens. If the verification fails a div is updated via ajax. If the verification succeeds the data is saved and the main menu is then rendered in the same update div as before instead of in the main default layout. I'm sorry if I'm not making this clear.

Comment: I tried your suggestion without success. The redirect in 1.1.x only accepts a url as the parameter not an array.